# Binding to an id in a frame that's showing a third-part website

Tags: javascript, jquery, frame, frameset

a) I have an html page that looks like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<script type="text/javascript">
  document.write('<FRAMESET cols="*, 300" border="0">');
  document.write('<FRAME src="http://www.my-website.com" id="inner" name="inner" />');
  document.write('<FRAME src="http://www.third-party-website" id="chatframe" name="chatframe" />');
  document.write('<NOFRAMES><P>You must have a frames compatible browser to use Activa Live Chat</P></NOFRAMES>');
  document.write('</FRAMESET>');
</script>

</html>
```

where the my-website.com frame is my website that I have full access to and where third-party-website.com is a website that I have no access to (it's a chat software).

b) Normally the chat would open in a popup, but we've done this so that it opens in a frame on the right side of the page.

c) The chat frame has a "close" link, which ends the chat session. It has a div around it:

```
<div class="close" id="close-chat">
```

d) What I'd like to additionally happen when the "close" link is clicked is for the chat frame to close, i.e. redirect back to "my-website.com."

I've tried using jQuery .bind() to add a click function to the #close div with no success.

Thanks for the help to anyone who is interested!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't provide any of your jQuery, but you mention a `#close` div.  Your div is `#close-chat` or `.close`, not `#close`.

Without more code, I can't tell you if this is the real issue.

If the div you are trying to access is on another domain, this will not work as it breaks cross-browser scripting security.

Comment: If add this jQuery:

`$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#chatframe").contents().find("#close-chat").bind('click', function(){
       alert('Hello!');
 });
});`

I do not see 'Hello!' alert when I click the #close-chat div.

Comment: The close chat div is in the external website?

Comment: Yes, the close-chat div is in the external website

Comment: Then you cannot bind to it as per security rules.

Comment: Ok thanks, so if I want a button to close the frame with the external website in it my only option is to put the button on my website? Or (maybe I'm misreading) but seems like I can use .attr [link](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to select the close-chat div and add a function to close it?

Comment: The button would have to be on a page on your domain, yes.

Comment: Should I be able to hide the close-chat div on the other domain? (so that users don't try to click on it)

Comment: Unfortunately, you won't be able to affect the external domain in any way.